# (C++) OOP - Brancing out with classes - beginner woes

Tags: c++, class, branch

First and foremost I'd like to state that I'm a beginner to programming. I was unable to find advice specifically about what I'm wondering.

I'm learning C++ through several books and am always putting into use what I'm learning by coming up with my own little ideas and coding them to the best of my ability. One such thing I thought of was a short text-based RPG with branching choices. In this RPG you have several different races and professions to choose from when you create your character. It's organized into several events, which may be influenced by your previous actions (or even by your character's attributes) - for example, if you picked option 3 in the first event, you might unlock an extra option in the second event. Or if your character is an X, you might be missing an option that others have.

I originally started with this only a few days after I started learning and coded around 4 such events in, it was fairly bug-free (but the code was very messy). Now that I'm getting into object-oriented programming, I decided to redo this program with classes. What I've coded so far is a "Character" class, containing data members such as race, profession, gender, and so forth, as well as member functions to get and set all of these, and a constructor initializing the creation (I'll add the entire class at the end of this post so you can examine that too, and point out any flaws or how it could be improved). The only thing I have in the main function is calling the charCreate function.

Basically, I do not know exactly where to go from here. I want to take a purely object-oriented approach to this. Should I make another events class? Should the events be part of the Characters class? How would I induce the branching using OOP methods?

I emphasize: the point of this question is to get advice from those with experience who can help set me on the right path and provide me with valuable advice that will help me grow as a learner.

Thanks

Character.H

```
#ifndef CHARACTER_H
#define CHARACTER_H
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Character
    {
public: //these are fairly self explanatory... set/get functions for the data members
    Character();        
    void charCreate();
    void setName(string);
    void setGender(int);
    void setRace(int);
    void setProf(int);
    string getName();
    string getGender();
    string getRace();
    string getProf();
private:
    string charName; //character name
    string charGender; //character gender
    string charRace;   //character race
    string charProf;    //character profession
    int charGold = 50;  //initial gold amount
    int charMana;   //this is only relevant for wizards, doesn't matter for other professions
    string profWep; //profession-exclusive weapons

};

#endif // CHARACTER_H
```

Character.cpp

```
#include "Character.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

Character::Character()
{
Character::charCreate();   //constructor initializes the character creation function below
}
void Character::charCreate(){

string name;
bool gender;
int race;
int prof;




cout << "\n\n\n\nFirst, what is your name? (23 characters max) ";
getline(cin,name);

setName(name);

cout << "\n\nAre you male or female? (0 for female, 1 for male)";
cin >> gender;
    while (gender > 1 || gender < 0){
        cout << "\n\nInvalid. Please select a valid option.";
        cin >> gender;
}

setGender(gender);

cout << "\n\nSelect your race: \n\n"
        "1 - Human\n"
        "2 - Dwarf\n"
        "3 - Elf\n\n";
cin >> race;
    while (race > 3 || race < 1){
        cout << "\n\nInvalid. Please select a valid option.";
        cin >> race;
    }
setRace(race);

cout << "\n\nFinally, select your class: \n\n"
        "1 - Warrior\n"
        "2 - Thief\n"
        "3 - Wizard\n\n";
cin >> prof;
    while (prof > 3 || prof < 1){
        cout << "\n\nInvalid. Please select a valid option.";
        cin >> prof;
    }
setProf(prof);
}

void Character::setName(string name){
if (name.length() <= 23){
    charName = name;
}
else{
    charName = name.substr(0,23);
    cout << "\nName too long; limiting to 23 characters.\n\n"
            "Your name is " << charName << ".";
  }
}
void Character::setGender(int gender){
if(gender == 1){
 charGender = "male" ;
}
else if (gender == 0){
 charGender = "female";
  }
}
void Character::setRace(int race){
if (race == 1){
    charRace = "human";
}
else if (race == 2){
    charRace = "dwarf";
}
else if (race == 3){
    charRace = "elf";
  }
}
void Character::setProf(int prof){
if (prof == 1){
    charProf = "warrior";
    profWep = "sword & shield";
}
else if (prof == 2){
    charProf = "thief";
    profWep = "dagger";
}
else if (prof == 3){
    charProf = "wizard";
    profWep = "staff";
  }
}
string Character::getName(){
    return charName;
}
string Character::getGender(){
    return charGender;
}
string Character::getRace(){
    return charRace;
}
string Character::getProf(){
    return charProf;
    return profWep; //the weapon is linked to the class, so I decided
                    //to have them both returned together
}
```

Comment: Can't figure out the question from all the lengthy text, excuses and sample! Have a point, the one you have isn't one, at least not for this forum ...

Comment: Having a deeper look (my retina is still flickering) I think you should get some knowledge about [class factory patterns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) and OOP [design patterns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns) in general. May be this helps ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A class should represent a abstract entity in your universe; if you create a `Warrior` class and an `Enemy` class, you will notice that both share similar properties (such as `life`). In this case, you may want to go up a level and create an `Entity` class and derive `Warrior` and `Enemy` from it.

None of this is necessary, however; you could write an entire program inside a class' method and have it work properly. What's truly important is the **concept** of object-oriented design; *what* should go *where* and *why*? Object-oriented tools such as C++ allow for assuaged implementation of these ideas.

Try and identify every existing and possible *objects* your program will have, and implement the classes accordingly. Currently, you have one `Character` class. The branching can be done inside the `main` function; there's no need to place it elsewhere, really. In fact, since your program is still too small, I wouldn't pursue an OO approach to this game (unless I intend to expand it to dozens of classes making full use of OO concepts such as inheritance, encapsulation and polymorphism).